# Can not clear couchbase alerts

Tags: couchbase

I had an alert for "Approaching full disk warning" on my couchbase cluster. I resolved the issue, but for some reason the alert does not clear within the cluster. How can I clear alerts within the cluster?

Comment: Did you find your answer?